# Mysql LEFT JOIN same table with WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, left-join

I've been trying to use `LEFT JOIN` to fetch student -> teacher and tutor. But it only returns one of them depending if the `WHERE` condition has `p1.user_id = :userId` or `p2.user_id = :userId`. But i would like to to fetch both the teacher and tutor based on the `:userId`

```
Students
ID | USER_ID | TEACHER_ID | TUTOR_ID |
1    5         3           4
Users
ID | FIRST_NAME| LAST_NAME | ROLE |
3    Lisa        Simpsons    TEACHER
4    Bart        Simpsons    TUTOR
5    Maggie      Simpsons    STUDENT
```

My Current query:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
LEFT JOIN students AS p1 ON users.id = p1.teacher_id
LEFT JOIN students AS p2 ON users.id = p2.tutor_id
WHERE p1.user_id = 5
```

Current result:

```
{id: 3, first_name: Lisa, last_name: Simpsons, role: TEACHER}
```

Expected Result

```
{id: 3, first_name: Lisa, last_name: Simpsons, role: TEACHER}
{id: 4, first_name: Bart, last_name: Simpsons, role: TUTOR}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need `left join` you should not use left joined table column in `where` but add it to related `on` clause:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
LEFT JOIN students AS p1 ON users.id = p1.teacher_id AND p1.user_id = :userId
LEFT JOIN students AS p2 ON users.id = p2.tutor_id
```

this way you get all the value in a row

```
SELECT s.*, u1.* ,u2.*
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN user  AS u1 ON u1.id = s.teacher_id
LEFT JOIN user  AS u2  ON u2.id = s.tutor_id
WHERE s.user_id = 5
```

but if you want the result on different rows youn need  union

```
select FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ROLE
from student  
inner join  users on users.id = student.teacher_id 
    and student.user_id = 5
union 
select FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ROLE
from student  
inner join  users on users.id = student.tutor:id 
    and student.user_id = 5
```

Comment: Now it returns other students -> teacher and tutor. I would like to return student which i specify with `:userId`

Comment: @Printer  add a clear data sample and the expected  result

Comment: you have posted only the expected  result and your actula result but you should also add  a coherent data sample for the tow table.. you should add  valid user data and valid student data  ..

Comment: Hopefully i made right update now. What i try to achive is that. I would like to fetch the student (Maggie) -> `teacher` and `tutor` information from `users` table.

Who her teacher and tutor is